# Swift 4: Azure DB with Facebook Authentication Callback method

Tags: facebook, azure, authentication, callback, swift4

app in swift4+xcode9 we are connection with DataBase in Azure with authentication through facebook.
in the App when launch the viewController, the login window of facebook appears.
I enter the user and the password but when the control will be return to the app will appears this window and stay there (nor return to the app control:

[window callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lle90.jpg)

this is the code of viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let cliente = delegate.cliente

    cliente?.login(withProvider: "facebook", urlScheme: "portfoliodispositivos", controller: self, animated: true) {
        (usuario, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Ocurrió un error al iniciar sesión en Facebook Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alerta.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("sin error en login")
            let tablaUbicaciones = cliente?.table(withName: "Ubicaciones")

            tablaUbicaciones?.read(){
                (resultado, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                } else {
                    self.ubicaciones.removeAll()
                    for item in (resultado?.items)! {
                        let ubicacion = item as NSDictionary
                        self.ubicaciones.append(ubicacion)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In previous versions of swift the login not included urlScheme and I do not understand what scheme it refers to.
If push 'Done' in the window the control return with error. I d not understand if the message is 'You have successfully signed in' why does not it come back without error automatically?

Comment: exactly, what is the purpose of urlScheme? I used it as the name of the app created in Azure portal.

Comment: In Facebook Developers: URIN redirect OAuth valid: https://portfoliodispositivos.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback

Comment: You problem is not very clear. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I have already edited the question. Thanks for the reply